# multiple button with one onsubmit

Tags: php, javascript

I am having two buttons in a form ques and ans.  When i click the ques button the same form with some text-fields will get open and in the form I've two buttons add and clear.  By clicking add the entered field will be entered to the database. Like wise the same thing for clicking the answer button. I'm having one onsubmit=return valid() for both the buttons. I've to write separate script for both buttons, checking the conditions. But I'd written for only answer button. I dont know how to write for both buttons in one function valid(). Please tell me how to write for both buttons inside a function.

```
function valid()
{

    var quest=document.getElementById('ques1').value;

    var cno=document.getElementById('cno').value;
    var pno=document.getElementById('pno').value;

    quest1=trim(quest1);
    pno=trim(pno);
    cno=trim(cno);

    if(quest=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter Question"); 
        document.getElementById('ques1').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if( pno=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter valid Page No");
        document.getElementById('pno').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (cno=="")
    {
        alert("Please Select Chapter No");
        document.getElementById('cno').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to add some screenshots

Comment: write separate validation for question and answer?

Comment: `onsubmit` does not occur on `<button>`/`<input type="submit">`, it occurs on `<form>`.

Comment: Ya onsubmit occur on form itself                                `<form action="a.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">`

Comment: All i have done in single form. Then how it is possible to write seperate validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
function validate(button_value) {
            if(button_value=='test1') {
                if(document.getElementById('rest1').value=="") {
                    alert('Blank for input 2');
                    return false;
                }
            } else if(button_value=='test') {
                if(document.getElementById('rest').value=="") {
                    alert("Blank for input 1");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The HMTL I tested in:

```
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return validate(this.submited);">
<input type="text" name="rest" id="rest" value=""/> 
<input type="text" name="rest1" id="rest1" value=""/>   
<input onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" type="submit" id="test" value="test"/>
<input onclick="this.form.submited=this.value;" type="submit" id="test1" value="test1"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ya it works fine. But i need to have some conditions for the test1,test according to their fields. How shall i do this. The test button includes some text-fiels in a form, and test1 button includes some text-fiels in same form. so i've to write seperate    conditions for the fields in that form.

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario a bit more

Comment: ya sure. my question and answer button is in one form. when clicking the question button the fields like question, chapterno,subject etc will be in same form and when clicking the answer button fields like statement,options etc will be viewed in that form. The add and and clear button is also common for both forms.In the script for **function validation()** i've to write conditions some thing like **if question some set of conditions and else if answers some set of conditions**. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Yes if thats the case then thonk it like that,
the submit button with 'test' id is questions button and 'test1' is answers button. So As I have stated in my solution check for this buttons values and accordingly do your stuff inside the 'if' loop

Comment: Ok. But please tell me what is that rest and rest1.

Comment: `rest` and `rest1` are the ids for the two input box. So what I did is if someone clicks on submit button with id `test` it will only check if the input box with id `rest` is blank or not, and if submit button with id `test1` is clicked then it will only check the input box with id `rest1` is blank or not

Comment: Thanks Roger. I did it with creating two seperate php files,giving link the question and answers. by clicking the question or answer link,it opens a new seperate form. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validate(this.submited);">
            Question : <input type="text" name="ques"> 
            Answer : <input type="text" name="ans">   
            <input type="submit" name="subques" value="Ask Question"/> <input type="submit" name="subans" value="Reply Answer"/>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['subques']))
                {
                        if(isset($_POST['ques']))
                        {
                            if($_POST['ques'] != '' && $_POST['ques'] != NULL)
                            {
                                echo "Your question is: " . $_POST['ques'];
                            }
                        }
                }
                if(isset($_POST['subans']))
                {
                        if(isset($_POST['ans']))
                        {
                            if($_POST['ans'] != '' && $_POST['ans'] != NULL)
                            {
                                echo "Your answer is: " . $_POST['ans'];
                            }
                        }   
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: I tried. But i am having the form ques and ans as in ques form the following fields are there. Question,subject,chapter. The same for answer form, the following fields are there. Statement,options etc. I've to do seperate conditions for those fields. How shall i do this.

Comment: Will you please tell me bit more about it.